# Using Notepad++ is there a regex shorcut for the sample code?

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++, shortcut

Using regex in Notepad++ and to find lines of data that match the pattern in the below two examples of data, is there a shorter or more efficient expression I could use other than the one I provided?

rise 0640 set 1933 (:) 12h 52m 58s - 2m 06s 106

rise 0640 set 1931 (:) 12h 50m 51s - 2m 07s 106

rise [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] set [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] (:) [0-9][0-9]h [0-9][0-9]m [0-9][0-9]s - [0-9]m [0-9][0-9]s [0-9][0-9][0-9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback, I know I asked for a shorter or more efficient way to write the code but after playing with it what I REALLY wanted was an expression that could deal with single-digit and double-digit units of time. So below is what I came up with and it works with the data I provided, but once again... THANKS!

rise\s[0-9]+\sset\s[0-9]+\s\(\:\)\s[0-9]+h\s[0-9]+m\s[0-9]+s\s-\s[0-9]+m\s[0-9]+s\s[0-9]+

rise 0640 set 1933 (:) 12h 52m 58s - 2m 06s 106

rise 640 set 1931 (:) 12h 50m 1s - 2m 07s 3

rise 0640 set 1931 (:) 12h 50m 51s - 2m 07s 99

rise 0640 set 1931 (:) 12h 9m 51s - 2m 07s 106

rise 0640 set 931 (:) 9h 50m 51s - 2m 07s 106

Answer (score 2):

You can continue shortening it from the original regex that you have given.

Here is the first compression:

```
rise \d{4}\sset\s\d{4}\s\(:\)\s\d{2}h\s\d{2}m\s\d{2}s\s-\s\dm\s\d{1,}s\s\d{1,}
```

I know this can be shortened further, but for explanation :

```
\d{4} --- Matches 4 digits
\s    --- Matches space
\d{2}[h,m,s]+ --- Matches 2digits followed by h, m, s
\d{1,} --- matches one or more of the digit pattern
```

Since Notepad++ does not support \d{4}

```
rise \d+\sset\s\d+\s\(:\)\s[\d,\s,h,m,s]+-\s\dm\s\d+s\s\d+
```

Comment: why not use `\d+` vs `\d{1,}`? (I mean overall, seeing as Notepad++ apparently doesn't do `{n}`)

Comment: @Mateusz Kowalczyk: Saw the comment and just checked out. Yup

Comment: Notepad++ definitely does support \d{4} from version 6. Tested successfully today in Notepad++ v6.1.2

Answer (score 2):

If it's anything like regular regex, then here is a shorter version that is equivalent to your regex: `rise \d{4} set \d{4} \(:\) \d\dh \d\dm \d\ds - \dm \d\ds \d{3}`
You forgot to escape parenthesis.

You can test various regex patterns at [this very handy website](http://regexpal.com/)

Of course, it could be made shorter but you'd most likely suffer on accuracy and if you have a lot of data, you could get false positives. Quick example of losing accuracy for some brevity would be `rise \d{4} set \d{4} \(:\) [0-9hms -]+? \d{3}`.

It's up to your data set and whether you want to sacrifice readability. This still matches `[a-z0-9 ]+? \(:\) [0-9hms -]+? \d{3}`
although you are really pushing it with what is allowed.

Decision is yours.

Comment: +1 , but notepad++ doesn't seem to support numbered repetitions, you'll have to use \d+ or \d\d\d\d instead of \d{4}

Comment: Notepad++ definitely does support numbered repetitions from version 6. Tested successfully today in Notepad++ v6.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Notepad++ but assuming it uses proper regular expressions, this works:

```
rise \d{4} set \d{4} \(:\) \d{2}h \d{2}m \d{2}s - \dm \d{2}s \d{3}
```

You don't really need to match the "(:)", though, so this would be a little simpler:

```
rise \d{4} set \d{4}.*\d{2}h \d{2}m \d{2}s - \dm \d{2}s \d{3}
```

Or if you want to capture the matched numbers for backreferencing (\1, \2, etc), then use parentheses around the numbers:

```
rise (\d{4}) set (\d{4}).*(\d{2})h (\d{2})m (\d{2})s - (\d)m (\d{2})s (\d{3})
```

And if you really trust your data, you can just accept any number of digits with "*":

```
rise (\d*) set (\d*) .* (\d*)h (\d*)m (\d*)s - (\d*)m (\d*)s (\d*)
```

(Note that in that last example, I put the spaces back around ".*" because otherwise the ".*" will match the digits up to the "h".)